# How can I write data to a file in the workspace of a blackberry jde?

Tags: blackberry, file-io, resources

I'm having a file in the workspace and I'm reading the contents of that file. I am able to display that content in an edit field. Now I want to know how I can, if I change the content of the edit field, update the file in the workspace. How do I perform a write operation on the file in the workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code I suspect what you are doing is reading from a resource file. You can't write back to resource files you will have to write back to a file either on the device internal file system (if you are on an OS version that supports that) or to the SDCard (if the device supports that).

Other options for saving data are the PersistentStore and the RecirdStore.